# Find a coefficient of $x^{12}$ in $(1+x^{3} +x^{6} +x^{9} +...)^{7}$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Find a coefficient of  $x^{12}$ in $(1+x^{3} +x^{6} +x^{9} +...)^{7}$

I don't really have idea how to solve that. I have only realized that we can get $12$ by:
$$ 12 = 12 + 0$$
$$ 12 = 9 + 3$$
$$ 12 = 6 + 6$$

But I can't see any further step that should be taken

Comment: Those aren't they the only ways to get $12$.

Comment: You need to add 7 numbers to get 12, including 0, 3, 6, 9, 12.

Comment: The function equals $(1-x^3)^{-7}$. Use Newton's binomial theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume that $1+x^3+x^6+x^9+\cdots$ is really $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{3n}$
which equals $1/(1-x^3)$. Its seventh power is $1/(1-x^3)^7$. This can
be expanded by the binomial theorem as
$$(1-x^3)^{-7}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty {n+6\choose 6}x^{3n}$$
etc.

Comment: But having example like: $x^{2}(1 − x)^{12}$ (again coefficient of $x^{12}$) it will be completely different thing as there is no geometric series right?

Comment: That's a different example (but still using the binomial theorem).